# How to quantify privacy changes for differential privacy with extra columns?

Tags: probability, differential-privacy

I just started learning about differential privacy (DP), and I've been trying to figure out how DP is affected when 1 or more column is added to the data. Specifically, suppose:

$$Pr(F(X) \in S) \leq \exp(\epsilon) Pr(F(X') \in S)$$

where $X$ and $X'$ differ by only one data point.

If I add one column to $X$ to create $X^+$, then by the definition of group privacy, I think the following is true:

$$Pr(F(X) \in S) \leq \exp(n \epsilon) Pr(F(X^+) \in S)$$

since each of the $n$ data points has been changed. However, is it tight enough?

More generally, if I add $k$ columns, then is the following claim tight:

$$Pr(F(X) \in S) \leq \exp(kn \epsilon) Pr(F(X^+) \in S)$$

or should it just be

$$Pr(F(X) \in S) \leq \exp(n \epsilon) Pr(F(X^+) \in S)$$

The former results from repeatedly applying group privacy when each column is added. But since each data point is essentially changed once when $k$ columns are added, I'm not sure if it should be just $n$ or $kn$.

Thanks!